# backup and restore db sql from C#

Tags: c#, sql, database-backups, database-restore, remote-backup

Good, I work on my application to perform backups and restore of an sql database. In local mode I have no problems.
Using `"SqlDataSourceEnumerator"` I get list of lan servers.
Start my application correctly, ready the available servers, I connect correctly.
The problem that I have when I want to create the path of my Savefile.dialog to locate the backups creates the backup in the machine of the SQL server and not in the machine from which I connect. My question is: how could I solve the route?

```
 S = save1.FileName;

Query ("Backup database" + cmbBase.Text + "to disk = '" + s + "' WITH INIT");
(Maybe in the route I should add the ip)
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: And how would SQL Server be able to write on a client machine? Should it connect over SMB to it? To which share name? Using which credentials?

Comment: Possibly just a type in your post but you have capital `S` for the filename but then in the query you are using a lowercase `s`. These would point to two different values.

Comment: @Joshua Hysong The error of the upper case was mine when transcribing but it is well in the application.

Comment: @SpaceUser7448 Thank you. Then that was wrong. Now I have to work on copying the files on the network to get to the end of my application.

Comment: @ SpaceUser7448 Could you give me hints on how to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BACKUP command in TSQL will not allow a network path to be referenced in the SQL command. So if you backup to (for example) C:\Temp\FRED.BAK, it will always be a path that is local to the machine upon which the SQL Server instance is running.

So to do what I suspect you want to do, you would need to - (a) backup to some folder on the machine running the SQL Server instance and then (b) copy the file from there to a central repository.

I would also add that the RESTORE command in TSQL also does not allow references to network paths, the file being restored also needs to be on a drive local to the machine running the SQL Server instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @DenisLarramendi - Can you vote up the answer if it solved your question

Comment: Thanks @DenisLarramendi